# Npgsql datareader throws error on ST_Intersects for particular database

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

using Npgsql 3.2.3 for .Net V4 framework i got a peculiar problem in my C# program.
When attaching to local PostGres database 9.5 (collate EN)
and execute a select with ST_INTERSECTS as follows:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select count(0)  as Total from XXXXXX  g  
where ST_Intersects(g.geom,  ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (92416.93536738542     452000.74351332453,92426.189685434016 451997.21004643326)')) "
```

*(XXXX is tablename)*

```
try
                {
                    using (Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader _reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (_reader.Read())
                        {
                            strResultaat = _reader["AANTAL"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I get a proper response. When executing the same query in code to other PostGres database (collate NL) I get error:

```
 Message: "Exception while reading from stream"
    RemoteStackTrace: null
    Source: "Npgsql"
ErrorCode: -2147467259
..
   StackTrace: "   at Npgsql.ReadBuffer.<Ensure>d__27.MoveNext()\r\n--- 
---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<DoReadMessage>d__147.MoveNext()\r\n--- 
---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>d__146.MoveNext()\r\n---
```

If I leave out the `ST_Intersects` where-clause (so just simple select count(0) on same table) I get a proper response on both databases.

Performing this select in `PgAdmin4` to either one of the databases gives me correct results again.

Am I missing something ?

**Update:** 
after changing the collate/characterset of both databases to same and some more testing, still puzzled, adding

```
  CommandTimeout=0;TimeOut=0;Keepalive=0;Pooling=false;
```

to ConnectionString didn't help.

this works

```
  select count(0) as Total from vw_bkk g  where ST_Intersects(g.GEOM, ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (92416.93536738542     452000.74351332453,92426.189685434016 451997.21004643326)'))
```

but this won't :

```
 select count(0) as Total from vw_bkk g  where ST_Intersects(g.GEOM, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((92435.107224574778 452020.56550608773, 92436.9042605573 452019.77627840184, 92437.781275783462 452019.33857956366, 92441.100836461876 452017.25236467138, 92441.875609279086 452016.65197891078, 92444.724385195354 452013.95823589037, 92445.367141518756 452013.21823569539, 92447.635655810838 452010.02048358152, 92448.121694875386 452009.1693067447, 92449.722769812055 452005.59043335693, 92450.033413409081 452004.66079012671, 92450.905520578031 452000.8383295628, 92451.0288308483 451999.86594560725, 92451.138455660257 451995.94679288281, 92451.069693859245 451994.96903637191, 92450.412623494063 451991.10380232794, 92450.154432099211 451990.15824789618, 92448.755917402814 451986.49547131034, 92448.318218564644 451985.61845608416, 92446.232003672034 451982.2988954052, 92445.631617911422 451981.524122588, 92442.93787489098 451978.67534667178, 92442.197874696 451978.03259034839, 92439.00012258286 451975.76407605677, 92  438.148945746027 451975.27803699218, 92434.57007235699 451973.676962055, 92433.640429126783 451973.366318458, 92429.8179685644 451972.49421128939, 92428.845584608818 451972.37090101908, 92424.926431882632 451972.26127620705, 92423.94867537175 451972.33003800811, 92420.083441328767 451972.9871083732, 92419.137886896991 451973.24529976805, 92417.272146293253 451973.85458677879, 92408.017828244658 451977.38805367006, 92406.220792262131 451978.17728135595, 92405.343777035974 451978.61498019414, 92402.02421635756 451980.70119508641, 92401.24944354035 451981.301580847, 92398.400667624082 451983.99532386742, 92397.75791130068 451984.73532406241, 92395.4893970086 451987.93307617627, 92395.00335794405 451988.78425301309, 92393.402283007381 451992.36312640086, 92393.091639410355 451993.29276963108, 92392.2195322414 451997.115230195, 92392.096221971136 451998.08761415054, 92391.986597159179 452002.006766875, 92392.055358960191 452002.98452338588, 92392.712429325373 452006.84975742985, 92392.970620720225 452007.7953118616  1, 92394.369135416622 452011.45808844746, 92394.806834254792 452012.33510367363, 92396.8930491474 452015.65466435259, 92397.493434908014 452016.42943716981, 92400.187177928456 452019.278213086, 92400.927178123442 452019.9209694094, 92404.124930236576 452022.189483701, 92404.976107073409 452022.67552276561, 92408.554980462446 452024.27659770282, 92409.484623692653 452024.5872412998, 92413.307084255037 452025.4593484684, 92414.279468210618 452025.58265873871, 92418.1986209368 452025.69228355074, 92419.176377447686 452025.62352174969, 92423.041611490669 452024.96645138459, 92423.987165922445 452024.70825998974, 92425.852906526183 452024.098972979, 92435.107224574778 452020.56550608773))'))
```

And in same database on different tables:
doesn't work

```
  strSQL=" select count(0) as Total from QS_VW_GEO g  where ST_Intersects(g.GEOM, ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (92416.93536738542     452000.74351332453,92426.189685434016 451997.21004643326)')) "
```

does work

```
     strSQL=" select count(0) as Total from QS_TB_GEO g  where ST_Intersects(g.GEOM, ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (92416.93536738542     452000.74351332453,92426.189685434016 451997.21004643326)')) "
```